# Android Virtual Machines Problems

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

My real problem is that i have the possibility to run my android apps into a single virtual device machine (Nexus S), the other devices loads for a long time but in vain they stuck.

My questions are : 1. Is it because of compatibility problem with my Laptop CPU (Dual Core) ? 2. If not, is there a solution for this issue ? Can you help me, please?

**Edit:
I realized that I had this problem because of the processor of my computer. It was not compatible with both IDE-s: Eclipse and Android Studio. So I changed my computer.**

Comment: I don't think we can solve your problem with this little information. Try downloading new virtual devices or try [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) (It's only free for personal use) or any of the other android emulators out there. Read the documentation to see if your device meets the minimum requirements.

Comment: i tried Genymotion, it has the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I had this problem because of the processor of my computer. It was not compatible with both IDE-s: Eclipse and Android Studio. So I changed my computer.